# Proper File Name Conventions for File Indexes

Tags: apache, filenames

I have a subdomain set up as an online file index. However, I am interested in the best practices for filenames. For example, all of my directories are lowercase, but some of my files contain uppercase letters. Is this standard practice? If not, what are more acceptable options?

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the link to the previous answers.  I wondered if Apache had a setting to make urls case insensitive.  Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply my opinion, based on coding and user usability observations.  Though there may be a formal standard form for this, I've not seen it formulated anywhere.  I think everything I've seen has always used a lowercase convention.

Since you're using an Apache server, your file names are case-sensitive.  Though you may know the file convention  yourself, your end users may not.  Should a user ever need to type in the url path in the address bar, using a mixed case might create difficulties for them.

If your users will never type in the address and you'll handle the mixed case scenario you're currently using in your code, then use what is easiest for you to read your files.  However, I personally would leave everything lowercase just to make it easier for me when coding.